# Find rows in A that don't have an associated row in B, where the FK is on B?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What I've been doing is

```
SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON b.a_id=a.id WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

Basically, I'm trying to find the rows of `a` that don't have an associated `b`, where the foreign key is stored on `b`. Is this the proper way to do it, or there a different kind of join to do this?

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  a
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE a_id = a.id)
```

Having an index on `b.a_id` helps the performance of this query.

Comment: @Denis: Certainly not. When there is an index on `b.a_id`, this is going to be blazingly fast.

Comment: +1 - See also: [Left outer join vs NOT EXISTS](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/)

Comment: Although the format of the query suggests that the EXISTS is checked for each individual record as a seperate query, this is not the case.  The optimisation process is able to understand the relationship in a very similar was to a traditional JOIN, and thus it is actually exceptionally efficient.

Comment: I think this is the better way.

Comment: @Tomalak: Unless the planner rewrites it as a left join or not in clause, using not exists and a subquery will stick you with a nested loop over the entire table -- i.e. it'll be visiting the index on b, once per row in a. His current query, by contrast, will join the two sets (basically a with b) and this will be considerably faster.

Comment: @Denis: There is no difference between a JOIN and an EXISTS sub-query. Both operations need to check every row in `a` against (ideally) an index in `b`.

Comment: Indeed they do from a semantic standpoint, but the query planner treats them differently depending on the database. In particular MySQL, which I'm 90% certain will execute one subquery per row.

Comment: @Denis: And what does it do for a JOIN, then? The term "sub-query" aside, how is finding a matching row in an index via a JOIN different (or more efficient, for that matter) than finding a matching row via EXISTS? *(Not a trick question, I'm really interested if I'm wrong here)*

Comment: Tomalak: it does exactly what I'm saying. See for yourself: http://pastebin.com/ZCDgjwwH

Comment: Re your other question, in one case each table is *sequentially* read once. In the other, a is read once, and looped through sequentially, while b is *randomly* looped through (or its index, if index-only scans are available) as many times as there are rows in a. That works well in the article Joe pointed to *because b is small*; you'll get awkward results if b won't fit in memory.

Comment: Joe posted that link on another thread, got me to do some experimenting earlier. On Postgres, the `NOT EXISTS` and `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` generated the same plan, at least under the particular random data I put in. I would choose between these only on the basis of an actual test with the table size and data distribution of the problem at hand. (MySQL, for example, may have totally different optimization.) All other things equal I find the `JOIN` a little easier to read just bc it is shorter.

Comment: @Andrew: "On Postgres, the NOT EXISTS and LEFT JOIN/IS NULL generated the same plan" -- Actually, if you look at the pastebin I linked to, the plans are slightly different (right hash join on table1 vs anti-join on table2). Postgres will rewrite the anti-join as needed -- MySQL just won't.

Answer (score 5):

yes, that is the normal way, i don't know of a better way.

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
Select * from a where a.id not in (Select a_id from b)
```

Comment: @Andrea Girardi: For one, this should be (`select a_id from b`), and other than that this will fail if there is `NULL` among the values returned from the sub-query.

Answer (score 1):

The three previous response are correct, at this point I think you can considere the performance of the three kind of query. You can take a look to this URL:

http://rockycode.com/blog/not-vs-outer-join-performance/

In my opinion I think that outer join is the best way and, if you have not too much rows, the three way are more or less equals.