# Get table records except the ones that has foreign key values in another table

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables:

```
goods:  id | name

imported_goods: id | good_id | amount
```

**imported_goods** has foreign key values from table **goods**, And what i'm trying to do is:

> Display all **goods** records *Except* the records that has foreign
> key values in **imported_goods**.

Example (CSV):

**goods**

```
1,orange
2,apple
3,bannana
4,mango
```

**imported_goods**

```
1,1,20 kg
2,2,40 kg
3,3,60 kg
```

Expected Result:

```
4,mango
```

And all other records discarded

**Good Model**

```
class Good extends Model
{        
     /**
     * Get the Imported Goods for this Good.
     */
    public function imported_goods()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Imported_good','good_id');
    }
}
```

**Imported_Good Model**

```
class Imported_good extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the Good info for this Imported Good.
     */
    public function good()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Good','good_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result too. ([mcve])

Comment: @jarlh Added Sample with expected results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find rows in A that don't have an associated row in B, where the FK is on B?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190409/find-rows-in-a-that-dont-have-an-associated-row-in-b-where-the-fk-is-on-b)

Comment: @Rob Streeting Yeah it does, But its answers are raw SQL queries where here i want it in eloquent relationship, Because i'm using Laravel. El_vanja Answer is great, But its not really benefiting from the Eloquent Engine and Nether that Question Thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you followed good practice and recommendation of naming convention between table names, model names, keys, fields etc ([like here for example](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices)), you can do it just with:

```
// Parent.php model 
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Child::class);
}

// than somewhere in controller
$parents = Parent::doesntHave('children')->get();
```

This is generic example. If you share actual names and model classes code as much as table structure instead of some x/y placeholders, I'll be able to tell more for your particular case.

Comment: I added real Table Names & Columns with their respected Models and relationships, I used **X** & **Y** just to make it simpler and not too complicated.

Comment: No i don't have a valid way to test this, But i'll try it later and see if it works.

Comment: I'm almost certain it'd work from your shown code. Let me know if doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize a subquery:

```sql
SELECT * FROM X WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT x_id FROM Y);
```

Or you can perform a join:

```sql
SELECT X.* FROM X LEFT JOIN Y ON X.id = Y.x_id WHERE y.x_id IS NULL;
```

If you don't have to worry about performance, I'd suggest the first option (it's more readable and easier to understand). If you need to, consider that [joins are generally faster than subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query).

Comment: Is it possible using Eloquent Models?

Comment: Of course. Just follow the syntax for [subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064678/how-to-create-a-subquery-using-laravel-eloquent) or [joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins).